# Folder becomes invalid after trying to create a nameless folder inside it by mistake!

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

My first post on stackexchange.
I was trying to change the name of a folder inside another folder in my extsdcard. I cut the name. But unfortunately pressed the rename button before inserting  a new name for the folder. Now the parent folder becomes empty, only a file named "invalid " (0.0 byte) is in it.  Other files & folders are not there. 
Is it possible to recover the files?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put your SD card into a linux computer.

Then make as soon as possible a dump of your SD card using `dd`. In this way you'll get an image which you can use for recovery trials and avoid to brick your original device.

Then you can use this image (or a copy if you modify it) for your trials.

- First try just to mount it and see, if it possible to access it and the relevant files.
- If this does not help, you should use `fsck` to hopefully recover your lost files, results are typically stored in the directory `lost+found`.
- If this all does not help, you should use a tool like `testdisk` to recover all kind of lost and deleted files. (However, this method will be most likely have a chance to be successfull, if there have not been to much write operations on the SD card, as every write operation might overwrite any lost files).